# Custom event for electron webview that fires after asynchronous code has finished executing

Tags: javascript, electron

So as the title suggests, I am loading a `webview` in Electron and I need it to fire an event **after** the asynchronous code in this webview has finished executing. Now, the `dom-ready` event is fired as soon as the synchronous code has finished executing so I am unable to use it. Is there any other event that I can try (as far as I know, there isn't - I've checked)? Or, is there any way to set up a custom event that can be fired after the script execution. Any help is appreciated.

P.S: I can't post the code here and I think the question is self-explanatory.

Comment: Can you run some code in the webview as soon as your asynchronous code has finished executing?

Comment: @Joshua Could you give me a bit more context of what you mean here? What do you mean by "run some code in the webview"?? I can run code in, say the `then()` part of the async code or I could call a callback after the async code has finished executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Electron's inter-process-communication (IPC) to achive this.

First you need to send a message from the webview (renderer process) to the main process like this:

```js
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipcRenderer.send('async-code-finished');
```

Then recieve the message in your main-process:

```js
var ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
ipcMain.on('async-code-finished', function () {
    // Do what you want here.
});
```

If that doesn't work check your `BrowserWindow` `webPreferences` settings:

- `nodeIntegration` should be set to `true`.
- `contextIsolation` should be set to `false`.

Like this:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences:  {
        nodeIntegration:  true,
        contextIsolation: false
    },
});
```

Read more:

- [`ipcMain`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)
- [`ipcRenderer`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up doing the same with the only difference being that, I added an event listener to the webview and accessed the event `ipc-message` from there. Your answer is appreciated.